# Blazor running in VS2019 works in debug but not release

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mono, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing a blazor application using VS 2019.  The app works great in debug mode - it compiles builds and runs without an issue.  But I switch to Release or try to publish the app using the "Publish..." option, I get the following errors below.  Any ideas?

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       Unhandled exception. Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method:
 'System.String Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.DateTimeFormatter::ToRfc1123String(System.DateTimeOffset,System.Boolean)' in assembly: 'Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll'  SRBlazer    C:\Users\MyselfLenovo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.0\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets    326 


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ILLink failed with exit code -532462766.    SRBlazer



Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: SRBlazer, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>Fatal error in Mono IL Linker
1>C:\Users\MyselfLenovo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.0\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(326,5): error : Unhandled exception. Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.String Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.DateTimeFormatter::ToRfc1123String(System.DateTimeOffset,System.Boolean)' in assembly: 'Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll'
1> ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.InplaceStringBuilder
1>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
1>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
1>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
1>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
1>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
1>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
1>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
1>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
1>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
1>   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
1>   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
1>   at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run(ILogger customLogger)
1>   at Mono.Linker.Driver.Execute(String[] args, ILogger customLogger)
1>   at Mono.Linker.Driver.Main(String[] args)
1>C:\Users\MyselfLenovo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.0\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(326,5): error : ILLink failed with exit code -532462766.
1>Done building project "SRBlazer.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: https://github.com/mono/linker/issues/1457

Comment: @LexLi Thanks but there tons of dead-end bugs about this in github where the issue just gets bounced around from one repo to another.  The one you mentioned is one of them.  For me updating to 5.0 is not a solution.

Comment: You have to understand that Blazor on .NET Core 3.1 was not mature enough in many areas but released earlier in 2020, and Microsoft only had a chance to solve the major issues (BCL and tooling) in .NET 5 time frame. So refusing to upgrade only restricts how much you can gain from Blazor.

Comment: Thanks again Lex.  Makes sense.  I will update to 5.0. Same thing happened to me when I learned angular.js.

Answer (score 1):

I had this row to my project file (*.csproj)

```
<BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>
```

under the tag PropertyGroup and everything works for me. Try it.

Comment: This fixed in for me on a Blazor WebAssembly hosted solution.